# Assignment operator works fine as a condition in if Statement in C programs

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am aware that when a non zero value is provided as a condition in an if statement, the condition is evaluated to be true.

Yet, I'm wondering how an **assignment(=)** is evaluated to be true here, instead of a comparison(==), and runs without any errors in the below C program.

```
int main(){
int a, b =5;

if(a=10) {
   ("This works");
}

if(b=1){
   ("This works too");
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator always returns the value that was assigned. So in your case `a=10` has the value `10` and the if statement is essentially `if(10)`. Which is true.

Answer (score 1):

1. `a = 10` is an expression that assigns 10 to `a` and whose value is the result of the assignment (that is 10).
2. any value different from 0 is considered to be `true`

Try this:

```
if (b = 0) {
   ("This is never displayed");
}
```